# Installed module pysubgroup not found in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to use the pysubgroup python package referenced [here](https://github.com/flemmerich/pysubgroup).

I think I properly installed it as shown below, with no errors when I installed it:

```
> mymacs-MacBook-Pro:dq-pattern-research mymac$ pip3 search pysubgroup
> pysubgroup (0.5.4)  - pysubgroup is a Python library for the data
> analysis
>                       task of subgroup discovery.   INSTALLED: 0.5.4 (latest) mymacs-MacBook-Pro:dq-pattern-research mymac$ pip3 install
> pysubgroup Requirement already satisfied: pysubgroup in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (0.5.4) Requirement already satisfied: pandas in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from pysubgroup) (0.23.4) Requirement already satisfied: scipy in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from pysubgroup) (1.1.0) Requirement already satisfied: numpy in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from pysubgroup) (1.15.1) Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib
> in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from pysubgroup) (2.2.3) Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k
> in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from pandas->pysubgroup) (2018.5) Requirement already satisfied:
> python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from pandas->pysubgroup) (2.7.3) Requirement already satisfied:
> cycler>=0.10 in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from matplotlib->pysubgroup) (0.10.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from matplotlib->pysubgroup) (1.0.1) Requirement already satisfied:
> six>=1.10 in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from matplotlib->pysubgroup) (1.11.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from matplotlib->pysubgroup) (2.2.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> setuptools in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
> (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib->pysubgroup) (39.0.1)
```

But when I try to access it via jupyter notebook in Safari on Mac I get an error that it can't be found:

> import pysubgroup as ps import pandas as pd
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 import pysubgroup as ps
>         2 import pandas as pd
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysubgroup'

I also can see that it is installed in a notebook:
[![

---

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enetD.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enetD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right, I couldn't find out why this is happening, but according to the documentation:

> pysubgroup consists of pure Python code. Thus, you can simply download the code from the repository and copy it in your site-packages directory.

I cloned the repository from [github](https://github.com/flemmerich/pysubgroup), then ran the command:

```
python setup.py install
```

inside the cloned directory, then copied the whole directory (after running install command) to the site-packages directory, and it worked for me.

Here's how you can find the location of site-packages directory:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory

Comment: Thank you, this did work but I have only been able to import pysubgroup when I am in that subdirectory in site-packages or in the site-packages directory. Do i need to create a symbolic link or path to site-packages so I can start the notebook in another directory where I have my datafiles?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but since you copied pysubgroup directory to site-packages directory, you _should_ be able to import it from any place.
when you run the command `python -m site` do you see a path like this:
`/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`?

Comment: Here's the entire list: python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/Users/mymac/Documents',
    '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
    '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
    '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa',
    '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysubgroup-0.5.2-py3.7.egg',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/mymac/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/Users/mymac/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True

Comment: But my notebook has a slightly different path: ['',
 '/Users/mymac/Documents/daz-research',
 '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa',
 '/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/mymac/.ipython']